# Keyboard numpad separator key COMMA vs DOT

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have an **input field** of type number and when inserting a decimal place with numpad SEPARATOR key ("." or "Del") nothing happend when pressing it. That's because of localization settings on PC, some languages uses SEPARATOR key like COMMA while others prefer DOT.

Because of **type number**, input requires only numbers and comma. In this momment need to use regular COMMA key on keyboard that's not very intuitive.

Can I change acting of SEPARATOR key through JavaScript (key event listener) to always be comma, despite language set? How to to define adding comma to value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value inside the input field to have a comma instead of dot, you can check the value if it has a dot in it, and if so change the dot to comma.

```
inputField.onkeyup = checkForDot;

function checkForDot() {
    if (inputBox.value.search(/\./) != -1) {
        inputBox.value = inputBox.value.replace(/\./, ",")
    }
    // continue your code
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuf2D/)